# Gradle extension as source code in the Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle

I'm not that familiar with Gradle. I have a .jar that adds some functionality I need but I don't like having binary files in my repo. Is it possible to achieve it with the source code?

This is how I'm getting the functionality (irrelevant lines removed):

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files('custom-file-extension-windows-bundler-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    }
}
```

Can I somehow achieve the same putting the source code for that jar in my repo?

Thakns

Comment: Well, yes, of course. It will just be part of the source code of your project, that gradle will build. But jar files are usually stored in an artefact maven repository (nexus, artifactory, bintray, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code, you can add a gradle subproject that will compile the code and create a jar on build, and use this from your main or other gradle projects. The details are explained in the [gradle docs for multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html). You typically include that other jar like this

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':custom-file-extension-windows-bundler')
}
```

However, if your jar contains code relevant to the build itself, rather than the compilation, you would put that source code into the special [buildSrc folder](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources).